# Regex Match a string that is indirectly bound by 2 strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Here is my abstracted test string:

test test test

blue

test test test

red 23

test test test

grey

test test test

blue

test test test

red 99

test test test

grey - white

test test test

I am trying to match the text between the **second** "blue" and "grey - white"

Basically I'm parsing some code, and need 2 rules:

1.) Find red if between "blue" and "grey"

2.) Find red if between "blue" and "grey - white"       * I can't be sure of the order of the stanzas

The first one isn't too hard:  [Link](https://regex101.com/r/Rb2yNh/2)

But I can't figure out the second rule.  Everything I tried...
like  (?s)(blue)(.*?)(grey(?!\s+test))
... still matches the first "blue", instead of skipping over it

Is there away to turn (.*?) into 'but only if does not contain "blue" '

Anyone know a trick I do not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this based on your 2 rules although they don't match your regex.  [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rb2yNh/5)

```
(blue).*?[^ ](red) .*?[^ ](grey( | - blue)?)
```

Match 'blue' followed by a non greedy match of anything until the next 'red' (where red is proceeded by the start of a line or a space, and followed by a space) followed by a non-greedy match of anything until followed by 'grey' (where grey is proceeded by the start of a line or a space) which is itself optionally followed by a space or ' - blue'. Ensuring the match word is proceeded by a space rules out false matches where 'red' is part of another word.

Answer (score 0):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dbdhDu/1) `(?s)(blue)(.*?)(grey(?!\s+test))`  will match the whole part between the first blue and the last grey because of the negative lookahead `(grey(?!\s+test))` which does match in the middle and fails the negative lookahead.

What you might do is capture blue and then use a greedy match to match the last "red" followed by 1+ digits. Then use a non greedy pattern to match until the first "grey - white"

```
(?s)(blue).*(red \d+).*?(grey - white)
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DowsBc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?s)(blue).*?(red).*?(grey(?: - blue)?)
```

The above regex matches BOTH reds... but I need to be able to tell which is which (I can't rely on their order)

.

Let me re-write the question to clarify the objective:

I need two regex, I already found an answer for 1.), but am looking for an answer for 2.):

1.) Find "red XX" if between "blue" and "grey"    (match contains only **red 23**)

2.) Find "red XX" if between "blue" and "grey - white"    (match contains only **red 99**)

Comment: I have update my answer. Instead of re-writing your question as an answer you could add it to the question instead.